# SQL filtering query based on number of related rows

Tags: sql

I have trouble wrapping my head around this problem.

After processing some queries I end up with a result of this kind:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM Whatever;

col1 col2
1    100
2    200
3    200
2    100
```

And I want to pull out `2` out of this, as `2` is the only value of `col1` such that it corresponds to every existing value of `col2` (`100` and `200`). If there was another row, say, `4     400` then I would want an empty result, as there would be no rows fulfilling this condition.

I was thinking `ALL` could help me, but then I realised that it's useless. I'd appreciate even the slightest hint as to what to read.

Thanks in advance.

UPD: After some digging I came to conclusion that I need relational division, i.e.

`Whatever <relational division> SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM Whatever`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm interested specifically in vanilla SQL, not the implementations of it. I don't want use any implementation-specific stuff.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Why `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` though? There's nothing in my question that implies anything related to count larger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select col1, col2
from (select col1, col2,
             count(distinct col2) over () as num_col2,
             count(distinct col2) over (partition by col1) as num_col2_per_col1

      from whatever
     ) t
where num_col2 = num_col2_per_col1;
```

Not all databases support `count(distinct)` as a window function.  There are pretty simply work-arounds, if that is necessary, but `count(distinct)` as a window function is standard SQL.

If you only want "2" and not all the rows, then use `select distinct col1`.

Comment: .great answer!!